# Angular2-directives. How can I pass the value into the template from my the directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have the template "starrating.component.html"

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let star of arrayStarts">
    <span class="glyphicon star" aria-hidden="true"
          [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="activeStar>=star? false : true"
          [class.glyphicon-star]="activeStar<star ? false : true"
          (click)="clickStar(star)"
          (mouseleave)="mouseleaveStar(star)"
          (mouseover)="mouseoverStar(star)" >
    </span>
</ng-container>
```

I have the component "starrating.component.ts"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'star-rating',
    templateUrl: 'app/starrating/templates/starrating.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/starrating/css/style.css']
})

export class StarRatingComponent {
    public arrayStarts;
    public activeStar;
    public selectedStar;
    constructor() {
        this.arrayStarts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        this.activeStar = 0;
        this.selectedStar = -1;
    }
    mouseoverStar = function (star) {this.activeStar = star;}
    mouseleaveStar = function (star) {this.activeStar = this.selectedStar || 0;}
    clickStar = function (star) { this.selectedStar = star; }
}
```

It's good works!
But I think a best practice it's using Attribute directives. Is that so?
I changed my code like that:
Template "starrating.component.html"

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let star of arrayStarts">
    <span class="glyphicon star" aria-hidden="true"
          [starHighlight]="star" 
          [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="activeStar>=star? false : true"
          [class.glyphicon-star]="activeStar<star ? false : true"
          >
    </span>
</ng-container>
```

component "starrating.component.ts"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'star-rating',
    templateUrl: 'app/directives/starrating/templates/starrating.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/directives/starrating/css/style.css']
})
export class StarRatingComponent {
    public arrayStarts;
        this.arrayStarts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    }
}
```

added the directive code  "starrating.directive.ts"

```
 import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, Renderer, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({ selector: '[starHighlight]'})

    export class StarHighlightDirective {

        constructor(private el: ElementRef, private  renderer: Renderer) { }

        private _selectedStar = -1;
        private _activedStar = 0;

        @Input('starHighlight') star: any;
        @Input('activeStar') activeStar: any;

        @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {this._activedStar = this.star;}
        @HostListener('click') onMouseCick() { console.log('onMouseCick: set star:', this.star);}
        @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() { this._activedStar = this._selectedStar || 0;  }
 }
```

Perfect works events into the directive (click, mouseenter and mouseleave).

The span element should be changed when changed the value of the variable "activeStar". 
like that:

```
[class.glyphicon-star-empty]="activeStar>=star? false : true"
```

But now value of the variable "activeStar" is defined into my the directive
And I try pass values into the template from directive
I try, but I just can't.

How can I pass the value into the template from my the directive?
Is there method better out there?

Comment: You can use @Output() in your directive to stream out of the activeStar property and toward the handler in a template binding statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `exportAs` you can assign a reference to a template variable and use it like

```
@Directive({ selector: '[starHighlight]', exportAs: 'activeStar'})
```

```
<span class="glyphicon star" aria-hidden="true"
      #ref="activeStar"
      [starHighlight]="star" 
      [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="ref.activeStar >= star? false : true"
      [class.glyphicon-star]="ref.activeStar < star ? false : true"
      >
</span>
```

(not tested).

Comment: Sorry, but don't work.
Error list:
Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "activeStar" ("r *ngFor="let star of arrayStarts">
    <span class="glyphicon star" aria-hidden="true"
          [ERROR ->]#ref="activeStar"

Comment: Can you create a Plunker? I'm pretty sure this should work. You see yourself that the directive does have the `exportAs`. Are you sure the directive is instantiated? You could try a `console.log('created')` in the directives constructor. Did you add it to `declarations: [....]` of your `@NgModule()`?

Comment: I create a Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/LGFlSjGiLRTzbIE6Msp4
now no error, but "activeStar" can't pass the value into the template
I can't find a tutorial about syntaxes (exportAs)

Comment: The problem is, that you get a `starHighlight` directive per glyph. See https://plnkr.co/edit/Dfw4Xo7GeGVjRHlDUlQr?p=preview. You could do it like https://plnkr.co/edit/hNg1UYWMqU2wl31X4972?p=preview but I think as component that contains all stars it would be easier than using a directive. It could also be done with 2 directives. One outside the `*ngFor` (like I did in my example) and one on each star. The star-directives could then inject the parent directive and updates it's active-star property (but the component approach would still be easier).

Comment: Thank you for help. That is what I need.
I understood how it works with your help.
The best practice at my example it's resolved with the component.